# Installing windows 10 on mac with bootcamp

Tags: macos, windows-10, mac, iso-image, boot-camp

I am currently trying to install windows 10 on my mac. I'm on `OSX El Capitan Version 10.11.6 MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015).`

I went here: `https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO` to download windows 10 ISO. After download, I moved the ISO to my desktop. I opened `Boot Camp Assistant` and selected the moved ISO file on my desktop. I then clicked install after selecting the amount I wanted to partition. After what appears to be an attempt to install, I receive the following error:

[Error after attempting to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyePk.png)

After receiving this error, I attempted to open the ISO file and I received the following message:

[Message when trying to open ISO file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJC6d.png)

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I appreciate any time you take to assist me with this issue.

Comment: Restart the Mac and try again. But your initial error message is due to network disruption when Mac needs to download Bootcamp drivers. All you can do is try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing with an ISO on the same disk that you are trying to partition.  This will cause a huge amount of IO as it copies the files from one location to another.  The "resource busy" errors are likely a result of the initial "Network problem" error.  You could try installing the ISO from a  second disk as discussed in length in this thread :-

[Link to Ask Different Discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164851/boot-camp-cant-download-the-software-because-of-a-network-problem)